# Is there a skill difference between players of the same Elo but in different region/server?

Tags: league-of-legends

My question is more **statistics and data proof** oriented than subjective. If possible I would like the answer  to include some "**cultural differences**" inputs.

For example, I would assume that a diamond in the Korean server might be worth a challenger in the EUW server (based on the last LCS). My assumption is that those differences might also exist between other servers.

*So is there a real skill difference? If yes, to what extent is this gap ? And the most important subquestion: **why** is there such differences?*

For example, what would be the Elo of a platinum EUW in the NA server? Please don't answer with only the LCS results as a support. A way of answering this question would be *for example* by comparing the farming of players of same elo, in different server. But once again the farming only cannot properly answer the question because (*for example*, it's an assumption), Korean tend to be more aggressive and farm less than European who are more passive in the early phase of the game.

Comment: If the question is too broad, you might want to focus solely on the diamond league between regions.

Comment: I've heard this same question before, but about Chess. In that case (and in this) the answer is 'yes'. I'm not sure how ranking (gold, diamond, challenger, etc.) factor into it.
In Chess, people often ask 'if my elo is X in USCF, what is it in FIDE?' (two different 'regions' if you will). The answer is, more often than not, 'you can't translate between systems because ELO is a function of the players in a system'.

Comment: I understand it's hard to translate, but still some elements (stat, data, cultural differences,...) could be usefull in (at least) understanding those differences if not being to translate them.

Comment: The easiest way to get some evidence about this is probably to find several players (across multiple ELOs) that have statistically significant number of games in multiple servers, and then use LOLKing or some other tool to compare. Assuming the player's skill level is static will yield a general difference in ELO in that range, and maybe differences in ranking. It would be impossible (or at least very hard) to accurately find two different players with the same (hidden) ELO and compare their play-styles based on some metrics that may (or may not) have much bearing on their ELO in their region.

Comment: This question is NOT too broad.  It asks a very specific question that is answered.  It is also a difference that is commented on by the player community frequently.  Heck it was mentioned in the last championship games that other regions practiced in Korea to up their game.  He even gives how the comparison is to be made, ELO to ELO.  As the up voted answer notes this is even a known problem with regional ELO systems.

Comment: Thanks Nick for understanding my question. I also understand that the answer might

Comment: Thanks Nick for understanding my question. I also understand that the answer might be very big in order to be consistant and to cover everything. Having said that, the person who would have answered the question completly would deserve a reputation bounty ;-)

Comment: If I could I'd reopen this.  It is terrible to have this specific a question that is based on METRICS get shut down.  It shows an almost comical lack of reading ability.

Comment: @nick I knew this question would only appeal to a few people especially since it is very specific but at the same time seems to be too broad if the reader doesn't have the same mind as we have to read it. I am not blaming this because the perfect answer of the question would be awesome and almost impossible, but still I was hoping for someone that would have at least brought some statistical/cultural/figures to give a beginning of answer.

Comment: @Jutschge, et al (can't sit them all evidently have failed to read the question or provide any information on why the question is too broad.  They have also blown past a reasonable answer.  I find this appalling.  Nor after the commentary here have the reviewed their decision and provided insight on it.  Also appalling.

Comment: @Kappei failed to provide reasoning.

Comment: @Rapitor failed to provide reasoning.

Comment: @Frank failed to provide reasoning

Comment: @Michel failed to provide reasoning.

Answer (score 7):

Quoting from [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elo_rating_system) here (emphasis is my own):

> The Elo rating system is a method for **calculating the relative skill**
>   **levels of players** in competitor-versus-competitor games

Since a ELO system only rates the players relative to each other, different "player realms" will inevitably come up with different ELO ratings for the same theoretical skill level, because the whole player base itself factors into it. Additionally the league system as seen in League of Legends or Starcraft 2 are just "sugar coating" on top of the Elo system in the background. These were introduced to give players a more motivating experience when trying to rank up, because say fighting for a top ten place in your league is more motivating than being player #115846 and trying to rank up to somewhere between #115820 and #115830 in the grand scheme of the Elo system in the background.

Having said all that my answers to your questions would be:

1. *Is there a skill difference?* Yes, a more competitive environment will usually breed better players
2. *How big is the gap?* Unknown, until you throw all players into the same elo system and let them duke it out against each other. You could try and compare data points (a lot of them) and find a translation, but that highly depends on the complexity of the game and I'd rate League of Legends as very complex because it's, first and foremost, a team game.
3. *Why?* See quote from Wikipedia.